# Java use Files.move to move file from one directory to other

Tags: java, file, move

I am using Files.move to move a file from one folder location to other after File is read.

File Read location : 
c:\doc\listoffiles\sample1\sample1.txt
c:\doc\listoffiles\sample2\sample2.txt

Files are moved to their respective location. Eg : sample1.txt should be moved to subdirectory sample1 and 
sample2.txt should be moved to subdirectory sample2

File Move location :
c:\doc\movefileto (this is constant)

The directory c:\doc\movefileto is already created.
I want to create a subdirectory under this say, sample1 and move sample1.txt sample1 is coming as dynamic value.
I am Files.move like below,

```
String st = "c:\doc\movefileto";
String dynamicFileLoc = "sample1"
Files.move(Paths.get("c:\doc\listoffiles\sample1\sample1.txt"), Paths.get( st+"\\"+dynamicFileLoc));
```

Its not creating the subdirectory, it is directly dumping the file under c:\doc\movefileto.
What wrong am I doing here.

Answer (score 2):

Files.move assumes the target is a file. You will need to call Files.createDirectory.

```
Path src = Paths.get("c:\\doc\\listoffiles\\sample1\\sample1.txt");
Path targetDir = Paths.get(st, dynamicFileLoc);
Files.createDirectory(targetDir);
Path target = targetDir.resolve(src.getFileName());
```